# uniScaleTransform not working for custom controls fabric 4.1.0

Tags: fabricjs

I have a custom control as [stated here](http://fabricjs.com/custom-control-render) and I wanted to unlock the scaling for the corner buttons with canvas.uniScaleTransform = true. However, it doesn't seem to be working for this latest version. Anyone got a workaround? Thanks in advance!

Edit: "Unlock" as in have the same action as when the "shift" button is held down when resizing the with the corner controls

Edit 2: [First Example](https://codepen.io/jacethemacerace/pen/RwaqGWO)When I add  `"canvas.uniScaleTransform = true"` on line 73, I'm able to freely scale the rectangle with the corner controls without holding "shift".

[Second Example](https://codepen.io/jacethemacerace/pen/PoNxGZY) However, when I attempt to add  to the custom controls  `"canvas.uniScaleTransform"` on line 2, I'm not able to replicate the free scaling behaviour. It'll only work if I hold down "shift".

Any work arounds is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you add a snippet, tryable, of exaclty what are you trying?

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi When I add "canvas.uniScaleTransform = true" on line 73 [here](https://codepen.io/jacethemacerace/pen/RwaqGWO), I'm able to freely scale the rect with the corner controls without holding "shift". 

However, when I attempt to add "canvas.uniScaleTransform" to the custom controls [here](https://codepen.io/jacethemacerace/pen/PoNxGZY) on line 2, I'm not able to replicate the free scaling behaviour. It'll only work if I hold down "shift". 

Any work arounds? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Fabric's Version 4 Breaking Changes](http://fabricjs.com/v4-breaking-changes), it has been highlighted that `Canvas.uniScaleTransform` has been removed and use `Canvas.uniformScaling` instead.

By setting `Canvas.uniformScaling` to `false` the objects **will not** get scaled proportionally when dragging the corners.

Hence, replace `canvas.uniScaleTransform = true` with `canvas.uniformScaling = false`. You can refer to my [CodePen](https://codepen.io/mingshanhee/pen/LYNMVwZ)

Comment: Your codepen has canvas.uniformScaling = true, however objects can be scaled in both X and Y. Not sure what is broken.